# If $M$ is finitely generated then $M/N$ is finitely generated.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $N$ be a submodule of $R$-module $M$. Prove that if $M$ is finitely generated then $M/N$ is finitely generated.

Help me some hints.

Comment: If $\mathcal{B}$ is a generating set for $M$, then show that $\{\pi(m) : m\in \mathcal{B}\}$ is a generating set for $M/N$ where $\pi : M \to M/N$ is the natural homomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose  $M$ is generated by $n$ elements, say $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$.

Claim : $M/N = (a_i + N \ |\ i \in [1,n])$.

$(\supseteq)$  It is clear.

$(\subseteq)$ Suppose $x + N \in M/N$ with $x = \sum r_i a_i$. Then $x + N = \sum r_i (a_i + N)$, as desired. Thus $\{a_i + N\}_{i=1}^n$ is a generating set for the $R$-module $M/N$.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.. To prove $x +N = \Sigma r_{i} (a_{i} + N)$, first we need to say that $\Sigma r_{i} (a_{i} + N) = \Sigma r_{i} a_{i} + N $ ,right? Though it's trivial to say.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  Every homomorphic image of a finitely generated module is finitely generated.

Comment: Your user image is rather unfortunate.

Comment: Your hint is nothing but a reformulation of the question. (-1)

Answer (score 0):

For every element, it's equal to a product of the elements of $B$, the finite set of generators.

We have then that for every element $a$ of $M$, $aN$ is equal to $(...)N$, being $(...)$ a product of the generators, then for every element in $M/N$, it's equal to that $(...)N$, so $M/N$ is generated by:

$$\left\lbrace mN, m\in B\right\rbrace$$

which is finite.

Comment: Not a product ...